# How to split a string in Java based on certain characters?

Tags: java, split

I split

```
String example = "That's called -- a cross-country vehicle!";
```

into an array:

```
[That's, called, a, cross-country, vehicle]
```

Using `String.split()`?

So far I've tried using `example.split(" ");` 
and using a for loop to print out, I am getting:

```
That's, called, --, a, cross-country, vehicle!.
```

However, I want it to ignore the `--` and `!`. I want to only print out words and words connected by word connectors.

Comment: This Question shows an lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split on a space or bang, plus optionally more dashes and spaces immediately following:

```
example.split("[! ][- ]*");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/zYllNg) of:

```
String example = "That's called -- a cross-country vehicle!";
String[] words = example.split("[! ][- ]*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Output:

```
[That's, called, a, cross-country, vehicle]
```